# No appenders could be found for logger - hadoop 3.2.1

Tags: hadoop, log4j

I am running multinode Hadoop(3.2.1) in my virtual machine. I have one masternode machine and one slavenode machine.

I am having an error on my datanode logs/userlogs

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Comment: This is not an error, and doesn't prevent anything from running, but read the link, and it explains the problem

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer, yes you are righ.